# How to get Tkinter entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

In this case, how would I go about implementing "OnButtonClick" so that when the button is pressed the user input of "e1" is printed?

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:    
    def __init__(self, master):
        e1 = Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        Button(master, text="Start", command=self.OnButtonClick).grid(row=4, column=0)

    def OnButtonClick(self):



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: LMGTFY http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm - `To fetch the current entry text, use the get method:`

Comment: @jon: seems like the OP is a bloody beginner and struggling, so let us be nonchalant ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to your `entry` instance on you App:

```
class App:    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        Button(master, text="Start", command=self.OnButtonClick).grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Now you can access `self.e1` from `OnButtonClick` and call it`s`.get()` method to get the current entry text:

```
    def OnButtonClick(self):
        value = self.e1.get()
```